# Very slow processing MySQL statement, how to make it perform better?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following MySQL statement that is performing very slow when the number of products to go trough becomes larger. The current statement is shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.*, colors.value FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_fields colors ON colors.product_id = products.id AND colors.name = 'color' 
GROUP BY products.id
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN merchant IN ('Merchant 1') THEN -1 ELSE RAND(1617116433) END,
    CASE WHEN category IN ('Category 1', 'Category 2') THEN -1 ELSE RAND(1617116433) END 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

To make it clear: there is a `product` and a `product_fields` table. For every `product` there are zero or more records in the `product_fields` table. One of the fields in `product_fields` table is a field: `name` with a value of `color` which is the only fields value I need in the results.

The `ORDER BY` statement is created because I want to display all products of a certain merchant first, and after that show the rest of the products from other merchants randomly. 
Next to that all products from a certain category (Category 1 & Category 2) must be shown first in the results. After that show the rest of the products from other categories randomly.

For the random I am already using a fixed number to randomize everything. It does not have to be really be different every time. I just want the rest of the products sort of randomly listed after the Merchant 1 and Category 1, Category 2 products are shown.

At the moment the statement **is working correctly**, although very slow on big datasets, I think the `ORDER BY` is making it slow, however I don't know how to fix this. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction on this.

EDIT >>
I have now run `EXPLAIN` for the above statement, and this is the result:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                                          | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                         | 10402 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | colors       | ref  | product_key   | product_key | 767     | dbname.products.id                           |     1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

EDIT 2>> To clarify things a bit more: 
The RAND is only used because I wanted every product to be randomly displayed after all the products from the specific 'merchant' and 'category' were shown. But next time the user visits the site the order can be the same, for all I care. I just want all **other** products to not be sorted by a certain merchant or category. So that is what that the `RAND` is  about.

Thanks to the brilliant answer of @spencer7593 I think it all boils down to the sorting of the whole resultset with the `Using filesort` option (see the EXPLAIN above). So now how can I fix this issue, with keeping a way to randomise the results as explained in the paragraph above.

Comment: What does an `EXPLAIN` return?

Comment: Well, for starters, there is no way to use an index to satisfy your ORDER BY conditions.  There could be other performance problems, but there is not way we can tell without understanding your table schema.

Comment: you're doing an `order by rand`, that's always going to be slow on large tables.

Comment: LEFT JOINs are way slower than INNER JOINs. If you don't need products with no colours (or if none exist) you should certainly change that.

Comment: I have added the EXPLAIN keyword and posted the result as an edit above...

Comment: Thanks, but using an INNER JOIN is not possible, as the products without a color should be showed indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `RAND(1617116433)` is going to return the same constant value every time it's evaluated. The same exact value is going to be returned for every row. That is, replacing that expression with a literal numeric value greater than -1 would produce an equivalent result.

If you really want pseudo-random values be assigned to each row, you'd need to remove the seed value from the function. You'd need to use `RAND()` to get a different value for each row.

As a demonstration, compare the results from:

```
SELECT RAND(1617116433), RAND(1617116433), RAND(1617116433) ;
SELECT RAND(1617116433), RAND(), RAND() ;
```

(Note that the second statement will return the same *sequence* of values, every time that runs. `RAND()` is a *pseudo-random* number generator, not truly random.)

Either way, in your query, the function will be evaluated for *every* row, and then the whole result set is going to be sorted. (EXPLAIN will show "Using filesort").

The `LIMIT` clause gets applied last, that whole resultset gets sorted, and THEN from the sorted set, the first 30 rows are returned. (That saves you from returning a bloatload of rows, but MySQL server still prepares that entire set.)

That's likely the biggest reason your query is "slow".

The usage of `DISTINCT` is a bit odd, you've already got a `GROUP BY` clause that ensures that the `id` from products is unique. The normative pattern would be to include `colors.value` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, do you need to return *every* column from the `products` table? We'd prefer to see the list of columns to return enumerated in the SELECT list, rather than relying on `*`.

Appropriate index on `product_fields` table may improve performance of the join operation.

```
... ON `product_fields` (`product_id`, `name`, `value`)
```

(We'd expect the EXPLAIN output should show "Using index" for that table.)

But that doesn't get you around the need to access EVERY row in the `products` table, and evaluate the `RAND()` function (two times) for every distinct value of `products.id`.

(A covering index on `products` table might also give a small benefit, but I expect that to be neglible.)

---

I'd write the query like this, but this doesn't do anything to get around the "big rock" performance issues:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.???
     , p.???
     , c.value
  FROM (SELECT RAND(1617116433)) i 
 CROSS
  JOIN products p
  LEFT
  JOIN product_fields c
    ON c.product_id = p.id
   AND c.name = 'color'
 GROUP BY p.id, c.value
 ORDER
    BY CASE WHEN p.merchant IN ('Merchant 1') THEN -1 ELSE RAND() END
     , CASE WHEN p.category IN ('Category 1', 'Category 2') THEN -1 ELSE RAND() END 
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593 for the great and very thorough explanation of the problem(s). Very helpful, I have already changed my whole statement as the one you propose. And I have added my comments on the proposed solutions above in my EDIT 2 >> of the original question. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Hugo: The inline view **`i`** is entirely optional; that's just one way to get the RAND() function initialized with a seed value. You could remove the inline view and `CROSS JOIN`, and just do  `FROM products`. That should get you a more "random" order each time the query is run *in the same session*. Or, you may want to consider varying the seed value with something like `RAND(NOW())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your query with `explain` keyword in front of the `select`. It will tell you what index, if any, is used.

Indexes is key to having good performance in MySQL. 
In this case it looks like you need index on colors (product_id, name).

Even so, this will always run a full table scan on products. You should try to add a limiting `where`-statement to your query.